# How to display query result in CGridView using DataProvider

Tags: gridview, yii

This 3 tables are just a part of my entire project (users,profile,login)

Login.php (**model for login table**)

```
public function topten_logins(){

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'concat(u.firstname," ",u.lastname) as Name, p.join_date as Joined, count(*) as Logins';
    $criteria->alias = 'l';
    $criteria->join = 'left join users u on (u.id = l.user_id) left join profile p on (p.user_id = l.user_id)';
    $criteria->group = 'l.user_id';
    $criteria->order = 'Logins desc';
    $criteria->limit = '10';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

and I have to display it in CGridView, and my code to display is as follows:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

    'dataProvider'=>Login::model()->topten_logins(),
    'enablePagination' => false,
    'columns'=>array(
        'Name',
        'Joined',
        'Logins',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

**I just want to display Top ten users who have most logins.**

But it gives me error message that:

> Property "Login.Name" is not defined.

I haven't used Yii before. So, your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are making query with 'as Name and as Logins'. In this case, what you need to do is to define 'Name' and 'Logins' as a variable in your model. in the class definition of your model add

```
public $Name;
public $Logins;
```

And it should work.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was messing up since last 14 hours for this 3 lines.. It worked well.

Comment: Hey @redGREENblue, will you let me know how to apply sorting on this ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the function "public function topten_logins()" in users model or in model where you have all the column names specified for CGridView.

else you can set column array as

```
$column['name']=>get name from user table 
$column['Joined']=>get Joined from related table 
$column['Logins']=>get Logins from related table
```

then set

```
'columns'=>$column
```

in CGridView

Comment: thanks for the help, but it didn't worked OR else i didn't able to understand it clearly.. the other suggestion from @redGreenblue worked simply, just tell me where to set column array?? ( inside the function or somewhere else )